# is there a way to save a block of JSON objects to a file in an SQL database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I have an application that records user events and the events X Y locations as well as other attributes at the time in an array of JSON objects. Right now using these objects I can do a live replay and rewind/stick to events which essentially just uses the saved data to recreate what the user did. This part works pretty fine, but I have been puzzled on how save this data to the database, the array is essentially a bunch of object instances that happened at the time of the event. I have considered saving it all in as a Text string but since it relies on X Y coordinates I don't want to have the client convert all of these strings into integers. Also saving one of these "records" would mean a whole lot of querying via the database.

So i was wondering if there is any way I can save this array of Json objects, or really an array of integers in one file.

Comment: Have you tried to store it in a `serialized` coulmn(http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class)?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no requirement to filter the data, then i think the best way to store any JSON format data to database is save it as **VARCHAR**.
We don't have to worry whether about any changes on JSON format in the future (from Database point of view).

Comment: yeah I actually need up just saving all of the attributes in a table set for arrays. But thanks.